# execute function in different shell

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, zsh, bash-scripting

I usually `zsh`. I want to execute a function in bash and return back to my original shell. I can do this manually, but I want to automate it. How can I do that?

For example, I am on zsh.
I want to execute `func`, which is a `function()` in  `bigscript.sh` file. I am sourcing the `bigscript.sh` file in my `.zshrc`
I tried adding shebang `#!/bin/bash` in the `bigscript.sh` file, but that does not change the shell.
I tried another approach of putting `function` in a standalone `function.sh` file and added shebang to it. It worked. However, I do not want to break the files into smaller `.sh` files.

So, any suggestions on changing the shell for a single function..?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski sorry, typo..

Comment: You should be able to schedule `bash` to take input from a "here-document". I haven't used this in `zsh`, but the facility seems to be much the same as in `bash`.

Answer (score 2):

Generally if you want to execute a bash function, you'll need to use the bash interpreter.  Some functions may work in zsh as it has a similar syntax, but there are differences that may be tripping you up.  Try this.

```
bash -c 'source bigscript.sh && func'
```

There are a few gotcha's with doing this.  If the function is setting variables or aliases, those will not be visible to zsh.  Also, if `bigscript.sh` contains any code that isn't inside a function, it will be executed when the sourcing is done, so be careful.  The last thing you want is for `bigscript.sh` to accidentally delete some files or make any other unexpected changes.  If `bigscript.sh` is just a collection of functions, you should be fine.  Your zsh session will be able to collect the function's return/exit code and any output it writes to stdout.

Comment: Actually its the other way around. `bigscript.sh` was written for bash. I am using zsh-5.4 for my daily development. This zsh version still has the bug for square brackets. So I end up using bash for executing functions in that script.